# I had completed level 1, but now I have not. what changed?

Tags: support, windows-8-challenge

I completed level 1 of the windows 8 challenge, but now my profile is listed as not having completed it. Why is this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your two questions tagged Windows-8 got closed, which probably means they no longer count.

Comment: This is correct. Closed question do not count towards the contest.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a clarification, this also counts as well for downvotes/unvotes.  The Contest rules state

> X posts with a **score** of X or more

This means the total score and not just upvotes.